# Do i need to install again drivers in dual-booting this OS?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers

Good day everyone, i'm planning to dual boot this OS to my windows 10 laptop and i'd like to know if i'm still going to install drivers like the wifi drivers etc. and if it still needed how could i install it?

ps: i had tried this OS before as primary os (replacing the windows 10) but it seemed that drivers aren't supported and can't install so i'd like to know if it will be the same if i dual boot it. Please be easy to me because i'm a newbie to this linux distribution :). Pentium 3825u with 10gb of ram is some of my laptop's specification

Comment: What drivers exactly do yo need (Which components of you computer are not working under elementary OS)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dual boot, both systems are separated, so you need to install drivers in both systems - especially that windows drivers and elementary drivers are different.

If you say that you used elementary before and had no drivers then tell us what was missing. Because some drivers come with the system, but some of them you need to install manually (usually by adding packages with a lot of drivers to your computer [as I remember I had to install package for DVD player in my computer]).

However, sometimes you need to download packages from producer's website (for example not common brands of printers requires this)  and usually they have drivers for linux.

In the worst of the worst situation you may not be able to install drivers, because there are only windows or OSX drivers. (In my whole life I had this situation only one time when I bought a new laptop 2in1 and there were no soundcard drivers for it [it was too new ;) ]. But some people reported that and after a while these drivers existed for linux :) )

If you are affraid that you'll have to install drivers for every small thing in your computer -wifi, sound, usb, hdmi etc. then you'll not :D [as soon as you don't have some bizzare computer from China or something]. I think that 99.9% of drivers for these most common brands exist and if not then it'll probably exist soon.

So don't worry and go for elementary!
If you'll have any problem, we're here to help you :)

Comment: Umm, Okay so nevermind first the driver, i install elementary OS yesterday but right after it requires restart since it is done ( i removed the pendrive right after its done installing) , it booted on windows 10 instead of linux. Is this common? I mean it won't boot to eOS so today i'm planning to reinstall it again just incase i did a mistake in installing it. I have made 3 partitions the root (i gave 10gb)  the swap value (20gb) and the home (170gb+) is this partition good or bad? Thank you!

Comment: And also dysproz, i don't have a permission in connecting this laptop to ethernet so can i just download the drivers needed in eOS using windows 10? then transfer the files to eOS? is that possible?

Comment: Hi so i reinstall the eOS but it still keeps booting on windows 10. I did everything shown in youtube tutorials and elementary os guide site but right after being install i remove the flashdrive then restart but keeps rebooting on windows

Comment: 1. It's common that sometimes after installing elementary os in dual bot with windows you don't get at start options to choose system. Starting your computer open BIOS (probably combination of ctrl and F<sth>) and find place where you can choose primary bootloader (if it's starting Windows by default so it should be called Windows Sth) and change to Linux grub bootloader (it has in it's name Linux, grub or elementary - I don't reember exactly right now, but I'm sure that you'll figure that out)

Comment: 2.Of course you can download drivers with windows and the transfer to your elementary on pendrive or wathever :) You just need to find packages on the internet. For example I looked up in Google or some common driver and I found this: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common
You can download here even older versions :) 
And one tip for you is that elementary is based on Ubuntu (Loki is based on Xenial), so you can always use everything that's for ubuntu.

Comment: 3.[Extra] If you have a dual boot with windows then you can access windows partitions from linux. It's listed in elementary files as a device (Probably Windows10_OS). However, to access these files you need to shutdown windows first, because currently windows is not shutting down when you click 'Power Off' button, it hibernates ( so generally it uses battery life when you don't need a computer, so to boot up quickly [I assume that Microsoft couldn't solve problem with slow system in other way ;p ).

Comment: To shutdown your windows już type in cmd or make a shortcut with command `shutdown /s /t 0`. Then you shuld be able to access windows files from linux. (notice that you don't need your windows password ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You will still need to install the the same drivers on the same computer under elementary OS whether you install two OS (as in dual boot) or only elementary OS (replacing Windows 10).

Actually the system kernel underlying elementary OS is Linux which is completely separated from the Windows kernel and its drivers.

This might help in your case: *with a working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible, please open a terminal and do*:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
cd ath10k-firmware/QCA9377/hw1.0
sudo cp *  /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
sudo mv firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1  firmware-5.bin
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/763080/no-wifi-in-qualcom-atheros-ubuntu-16-04-acer-aspire-e-15

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so you mean that there will be no internet first in elementary os when booted (i only use wifi)? can i download the driver through windows 10 then transfer the file to another partition where elementary os is located to install? And how can i find the right driver sir for my personal computer?

Comment: Actually you will have to find the appropriate drivers under elementary OS. Do you know the type of your wifi card?

Comment: No sir but if you can guide me where to locate the type of wifi card i can know it.

Comment: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Wireless Network Adapter, is this what you called wifi card? I checked this on device manager under network adapters

Comment: Hi sir, i'm putting every question i have in my mind because i'm going offline later. Another question supposed i already have installed elementary os, how can i make it boot first than windows 10? Thank you! :)

Comment: Another question, how can i install wifi drivers? what are the specific requirements needed for you to know what kind of wifi card is appropriate to my system. Many thanks!

Comment: I don't have permission to connect my laptop to the ethernet so is this possible to download the needed drivers using windows 10 then just transfer it to eOS?